# Why does a digital body weight scale give you the wrong result when put on a soft carpet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, weight

Why does a digital body weight scale give you the wrong result when put on a soft carpet? In particular, it gives you a smaller number.

My reasoning is that if the carpet compressed "fully" (which I guess is impossible, making what I'm saying moot), the number would be the same. However, when you stand on it, the carpet keeps compressing even without you being able to notice, so that the number on the scale is your weight minus the force that is being applied for compression.

Comment: It's probably because the carpet is pushing against a portion of the bottom of the scale that is not supposed to be pushed on.  In other words, the scale is designed such that only the bottom legs or pads should touch the floor.

Comment: I do believe that @James has the answer you are looking for

Comment: @James, I don't think that's happening, because the bottom of the scale has protruding parts that push against both a firm floor and a carpet. And even if that was true, how would that make the number on the scale smaller?

Comment: Imagine a case where there are four legs (one on each corner) and each leg has a sensor that measures the force felt by that leg.  The scale adds those four forces and displays the result.  Now imagine that there is a rubber ball between the floor and the middle of the scale.  The force required to compress the ball will not be included in the scale display.

Comment: @James, yeah, that's what I meant. The carpet still only touches the legs, but doesn't reach the middle of the scale.

Comment: Ok.  Just so you know, the explanation in your second paragraph does not work.  The only way that would make sense is if you and the scale were accelerating downward.  For example, if you stand on a scale in an elevator traveling down (or up) at a constant velocity, the display will read the same as if you were stationary.

Comment: A photo of your scale or a link to it on an online store might help generate other ideas.

Comment: @James, it's this one: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00F3J9G1W/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. But all of them do the same thing.

Comment: @Ryker : How do you know that the scale does not touch the carpet when you stand on it? Are you able to stand on it and see the underside at the same time?